# I'm new to flutter, trying to add a word to a list on btn click (the word comes from a text field). I then want the list to show on the page

Tags: list, flutter, dart, listview, flutter-layout

[Here's the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7c0I7.png)

If you look image, there's a text field and an add button at the bottom right. I want the user to enter the word and add that to a list using that button.

In order to access the value from the text field, I used (TextEditingController)

Please find the code for the widget below.
FYI: This widget gets called when an icon is pressed on its previous page

final wordList =  []; // list that I'm trying to render

```
Widget _doSomething() {
    setState(() async => wordList.add(await Navigator.push(context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Enter Something..'),
            ),
            body: TextField(
              controller: myController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                hintText: 'Add word',
              ),
            ),
            floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context, myController.text);
              },
              tooltip: "Toggle input value",
              child: const Icon(Icons.add),
            ),
          );
        }))));
    return _getList();
  }
```

Above, I return _getList(). _getList() is another widget where I have the list view code in order to display the word list values in the same page. (code below)

```
 Widget _getList() {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: wordList.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(wordList[index]),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

I apologize if something is unclear. Please feel free to ask me for more explanation. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

First you do not need to use new when creating instance of class. So `new Text()` will become `Text()`.

Second, if you use navigate use the `.of()` constructor, it will change your current screen. You can use the `Navigator.push()` method. The function would be `async` and would return of `void`. You can just retrun the widget in your main widget.

third, why are you returning a whole MaterialApp in a function. it should be in your `main.dart`.

```dart
void _doSomething() async {
    wordList.add(await  Navigator.
        .push(context,MaterialPageRoute<void>(builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Enter Something..'),
        ),
        body: TextField(
          controller: myController,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(), hintText: 'Add word',),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () { 
          Navigator.pop(context, myController.text);

        },
          tooltip: "Toggle input value",
          child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
      );
    })));
   setState(()=> wordList = wordList);
  }
```

For get list:

```
Widget _getList() {
    return Scaffold(
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: wordList.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(wordList[index]),
            );
          },
        ),
      );
  }
```

Comment: A couple of things, I added another async inside setState since it gave me this error "The await expression can only be used in an async function". Also, (Navigator.
    .push(context), the .push part seems to be a little off since it gives this error (The getter '' isn't defined for the type 'Navigator'.  Try importing the library that defines '')

Comment: I made an edit to the widget code above, however, when I click the add icon, the screen exits out and goes to the previous page. I'm not sure if that's because of the .push functionality

Comment: I have changed the code. I forgot you can't use async returns in a setState. You can check the code now.

Comment: for this line (wordList.add(await  Navigator.
.push(context,MaterialPageRoute<void>(builder: (BuildContext context))

Is Navigator..push a typo or did you simply mean Navigator.push ?